# TFS programmatically created Iteration nodes don't show up in Backlog items view

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I want to programmatically create Iterations in my TFS Server, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783216/programmatically-add-new-iteration-in-tfs).

I got that code working, but my created Iteration-Nodes, are not behaving like expected.

What is working: the iteration nodes are created, and they can be linked to any Work Item. They can be selected, like shown in the picture below:

[image]

All Iteration nodes showing up as "Iteration*" were programmatically created. Other Iteration nodes (showing up as "Sprint*") were already there.

But the programmatically created Iteration nodes don't show up in the Backlog items view.

[image]

Only the "Sprint*" Iterations are there.

What am I missing to get my programmatically created Iteration nodes to show up there?

Comment: How are you adding these iteration nodes? Are you using the new REST API technology or the old TFS API technology for that?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this works with the old TFS API, since I use the REST API. In this link you will find an example on how to create a product backlog entry: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09655793-1679-48ff-82d2-cc0280544d3d/error-when-creating-product-backlog-item-via-rest-api?forum=TFService

Comment: I am using the TFS API V15

Comment: Actually I find them too in "Add Itterations" in the Manage Area of my TFS Web Page

Comment: @Peter Update your question to include your code. It's impossible to troubleshoot a problem with your code without **seeing your code**.

Comment: @DanielMann I really just create the itterations like shown in the linked answer. It think my question is more about general tfs itteration handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterations which are selected in the teams setting will appear in the Backlogs hub for your team. Go to the team's setting, for example:

```
https://xxx.visualstudio.com/TeamProject/TeamProject%20Team/_admin/_work?_a=iterations
```

And select the iterations you want to show up in the Backlog hub, check the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add iteration in team settings for default team (or any another). You may find example here: [TFS 2012 API Set TeamSettings Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847885/tfs-2012-api-set-teamsettings-programmatically)

```
    // Set up default team sprint date and time
    var teamConfig = _tfs.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();
    var css = _tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();

    string rootNodePath = string.Format("\\{0}\\Iteration\\Release 1\\Sprint 1", _selectedTeamProject.Name);
    var pathRoot = css.GetNodeFromPath(rootNodePath);

    css.SetIterationDates(pathRoot.Uri, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));

    var configs = teamConfig.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(new[] { _selectedTeamProject.Uri });
    var team = configs.Where(c => c.TeamName == "Demo").FirstOrDefault();

    var ts = team.TeamSettings;
    ts.BacklogIterationPath = string.Format(@"{0}\Release 1", _selectedTeamProject.Name);
    ts.IterationPaths = new string[] { string.Format(@"{0}\Release 1\Sprint 1", _selectedTeamProject.Name), string.Format(@"{0}\Release 1\Sprint 2", _selectedTeamProject.Name) };

    var tfv = new TeamFieldValue();
    tfv.IncludeChildren = true;
    tfv.Value = _selectedTeamProject.Name;
    ts.TeamFieldValues = new []{tfv};

    teamConfig.SetTeamSettings(team.TeamId, ts);
```

Name of default team: "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME Team"

Comment: I will try this today if i get time